# How to automatically copy fields from one Sobject to another

Tags: salesforce

Im trying to create automation to copy `Zipcode__c` text field in connection sObject to `Zip_code__c` text field on Prem sObject. I can't use formula references since i need to be able to search copied field. One connection can have many Prems.

```
trigger updatePremFromConnection on Prem__c (before insert,after insert, after update,before update) {
    List<Connection__c> connection = new List<Connection__c>();
for (Prem__c p: [SELECT Connection_id__c,id, Name 
    FROM Prem__c 
    WHERE Connection_id__c 
    NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Connection__c) 
    AND id IN : Trigger.new ]){
                        connection.add(new Connection__c(
                        ZipCode__c = p.Zip_Code__c));
                   }
    if (connection.size() > 0) {
        insert connection;
    }
}
```

i need ZIp code field on the prem__c to be auto updated when i edit connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code.

#### Trigger Object

Your trigger is on the wrong object and is doing exactly the opposite of your stated intent.

> i need ZIp code field on the prem__c to be auto updated when i edit connection.

Your trigger on the `Prem__c` object attempts to copy data to the `Connection__c` object, while your objective is to copy from `Prem__c` to `Connection__c`. You'll definitely need an `after update` trigger on `Connection__c` and a `before insert` trigger on `Prem__c`; however, if the relationship between the two objects is Lookup or a Master-Detail relationship configured to be reparentable, you'll also need an `update` trigger on the child object `Prem__c` to handle situations where the child record is reparented, by updating from the new parent Connection.

#### Logic

This logic:

```
for (Prem__c p: [SELECT Connection_id__c,id, Name 
    FROM Prem__c 
    WHERE Connection_id__c 
    NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Connection__c) 
    AND id IN : Trigger.new ]){
                        connection.add(new Connection__c(
                        ZipCode__c = p.Zip_Code__c));
                   }
```

really doesn't make sense. It only finds `Prem__c` records in the trigger set that *don't* have an associated Connection, makes a new Connection, and then doesn't establish a relationship between the two records. The way that it does this is needlessly inefficient; that `NOT IN` subquery doesn't need to be there because it can simply by `Connection_Id__c = null`.

Instead, you probably want your `Connection__c` trigger to have a query like this:

```
SELECT ZipCode__c, (SELECT Zip_Code__c FROM Prems__r)
FROM Connection__c
WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new
```

Then, you can iterate over those `Connection__c` records with an inner `for` loop over their associated `Prem__c` records. Note that above you'll need to use the actual relationship name where I have `Prems__r`. The logic would look something like this:

```
for (Connection__c conn : queriedConnections) {
    for (Prem__c prem : conn.Prems__r) {
        if (prem.Zip_Code__c != conn.ZipCode__c) {
            prem.Zip_Code__c = conn.ZipCode__c
            premsToUpdate.add(prem);
        }
    }
}
update premsToUpdate;
```

Before running the query, you should also gather a `Set<Id>` of only those records for which the `ZipCode__c` field has actually changed, i.e., where `thisConn.ZipCode__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(thisConn.Id).ZipCode__c`. You'd use that `Set<Id>` in place of `Trigger.new` in your query, so that you only obtain those records with relevant changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Im learning the apex and this is very helpful. However , i'm still getting error message. Its in the next comment